# Three.js: How to add autoRotate in specific case?

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is the code:

```js
"use strict";
var OrbitControls = THREE.OrbitControls,
  CSS3DRenderer = THREE.CSS3DRenderer,
  CSS3DObject = THREE.CSS3DObject,
  Scene = THREE.Scene,
  PerspectiveCamera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera,
  Mesh = THREE.Mesh,
  PlaneGeometry = THREE.PlaneGeometry,
  MeshPhongMaterial = THREE.MeshPhongMaterial,
  Color = THREE.Color,
  DoubleSide = THREE.DoubleSide,
  NoBlending = THREE.NoBlending,
  WebGLRenderer = THREE.WebGLRenderer,
  MeshBasicMaterial = THREE.MeshBasicMaterial;
var CSS3DDemo = /** @class */ (function() {
  function CSS3DDemo() {
    this.scene = new Scene();
    this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 500);
    this.webGLRenderer = new WebGLRenderer();
    this.css3DRenderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.css3DRenderer.domElement);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
    this.webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.webGLRenderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF);
    this.css3DRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.css3DRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    this.css3DRenderer.domElement.style.left = '0px';
    this.css3DRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    var div = window.document.createElement('img');
    div.style.width = '160px';
    div.style.height = 'auto';
    div.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/1-month-old_kitten_42.jpg/2880px-1-month-old_kitten_42.jpg';
    var object = new CSS3DObject(div);
    object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    object.scale.set(1 / 16, 1 / 16, 1 / 16);
    this.scene.add(object);
    var planeGeometry = new PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(this.webGLRenderer.domElement);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(this.css3DRenderer.domElement);
    this.render();
  }
  CSS3DDemo.prototype.render = function() {
    var _this = this;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      return _this.render();
    });
    this.css3DRenderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.webGLRenderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.controls.update();
  };
  return CSS3DDemo;
}());
new CSS3DDemo();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>

<script src='https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'></script>
<script src='https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

I would like to add `autoRotate`. My try was adding this:

```
this.controls.autoRotate = true;
this.controls.autoRotateSpeed = 1.5;
this.controls.addEventListener("change", () =>
    this.render()
);

animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    this.controls.update();
};
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Why? Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to have a `change` event listener for on-demand rendering AND an animation loop. For using auto-rotate, use just an animation loop and update the controls via the respective `update()` method.

```js
"use strict";
var OrbitControls = THREE.OrbitControls,
  CSS3DRenderer = THREE.CSS3DRenderer,
  CSS3DObject = THREE.CSS3DObject,
  Scene = THREE.Scene,
  PerspectiveCamera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera,
  Mesh = THREE.Mesh,
  PlaneGeometry = THREE.PlaneGeometry,
  MeshPhongMaterial = THREE.MeshPhongMaterial,
  Color = THREE.Color,
  DoubleSide = THREE.DoubleSide,
  NoBlending = THREE.NoBlending,
  WebGLRenderer = THREE.WebGLRenderer,
  MeshBasicMaterial = THREE.MeshBasicMaterial;
var CSS3DDemo = /** @class */ (function() {
  function CSS3DDemo() {
    this.scene = new Scene();
    this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 500);
    this.webGLRenderer = new WebGLRenderer();
    this.css3DRenderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.css3DRenderer.domElement);
    this.controls.autoRotate = true;
    this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
    this.webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.webGLRenderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF);
    this.css3DRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.css3DRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    this.css3DRenderer.domElement.style.left = '0px';
    this.css3DRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    var div = window.document.createElement('img');
    div.style.width = '160px';
    div.style.height = 'auto';
    div.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/1-month-old_kitten_42.jpg/2880px-1-month-old_kitten_42.jpg';
    var object = new CSS3DObject(div);
    object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    object.scale.set(1 / 16, 1 / 16, 1 / 16);
    this.scene.add(object);
    var planeGeometry = new PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(this.webGLRenderer.domElement);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(this.css3DRenderer.domElement);
    this.render();
  }
  CSS3DDemo.prototype.render = function() {
    var _this = this;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      return _this.render();
    });
    this.css3DRenderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.webGLRenderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.controls.update();
  };
  return CSS3DDemo;
}());
new CSS3DDemo();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>

<script src='https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'></script>
<script src='https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```